# How to accept html input through textarea in ASP.NET MVC 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am using ASP.net MVC 2.0 , i have used a textarea on my View like

```
<%= Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description, 7, 35, new { @class = "bg_area normal" })%>
```

it shows me an exception while submitting the form after input html data like

```
<p><b> hello world ! </b></p>
```

is there any way to accept such kind of data using textarea ?

Is there any way to handle it from one place or, i have to add

[ValidateInput(false)]

to each action ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are getting

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the
>   client... exception. IF this is the case then you need to decorate your action result with

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
```

Comment: If you are using .Net 4 the, apparently, you will also need to set <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>

Answer (score 4):

If you want to post HTML to a Controller method you need to add the `[ValidateInput(false)]` attribute to your controller method.

[Here is the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateinputattribute.aspx).